# How to pass the value of id of element from form as array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

How to pass values of input form elements to an array?

```
var input = [{ 
    'FirstName': "$('#txtFirstName').val()", 
    'LastName': "$('#txtLastName').val()", 
    'City': "$('#txtCity').val()", 
    'EmailID': "$('#txtEmailID').val()"
}];
input = JSON.stringify(input);
```

I tried the code above, but it doesn't work? How can I build key-value pair form array and how to loop it using each function?

Answer (score 1):

You should execute it like that:

```
var input = [{ 'FirstName': $('#txtFirstName').val() }];
```

Your jQuery expression should not be a string!

---

The resulting JS four you should look like that:

```
var input = [{ 
    'FirstName': $('#txtFirstName').val(), 
    'LastName': $('#txtLastName').val(), 
    'City': $('#txtCity').val(), 
    'EmailID': $('#txtEmailID').val() }];

input = JSON.stringify(input);
```

---

Consider using jQuery formSerialize method to collect all the form data:

```
$('#myFormId').formSerialize();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below helper function which I am using for the same functionality-

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

Working Fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/sxGtM/3/